# Switch/case muito interessante em Swift - Quais outras linguagem suportam isso?

Tags: java, python, c, swift, pattern-matching

A linguagem Swift apresenta um modo muito interessante e bem intuitivo para se trabalhar com intervalos usando `switch-case`, com técnicas de "partial matching", "pattern-matching" etc., vejam só esses exemplos:

```
let age = 33

switch(age){
case let x where x >= 0 && x <= 2:
    print("Infant")
case let x where x >= 3 && x <= 12:
    print("Child")
case let x where x >= 13 && x <= 19:
    print("Teenager")
case let x where x >= 20 && x <= 39:
    print("Adult")
case let x where x >= 40 && x <= 60:
    print("Middle aged")
case let x where x >= 61:
    print("Elderly")
default:
    print("Invalid")
}
```

Outro exemplo muito interessante:

```
let string = "Dog"
switch(string){
    case "Cat","Dog":
        print("Domestic animal")
    case "Lion","Leopard","Pantera":
        print("Never touch me")
    default:
        print("By the way, don't touch... :-)")
}
```

Existem outras linguagens que possibilitam esses recursos? Em Java nunca consegui fazer um `switch case` assim. Também nunca tive curiosidade de saber se funcionaria :-) sempre usei uma abordagem de lógica diferente.

Acrescentando um exemplo incrível de "partial matching":

```
let coordinates: (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = (3, 0, 0)
switch (coordinates) {
case (0, 0, 0): // 1
    print("Origin")
case (_, 0, 0): // 2
    print("On the x-axis.")
case (0, _, 0): // 3
    print("On the y-axis.")
case (0, 0, _): // 4
    print("On the z-axis.")
default:        // 5
    print("Somewhere in space")
}
```

No caso acima, o programa analisará pelo padrão, dado que é um ponto em X e o resto dos eixos em zero. `"On the X axis"`. Em Java não usaria um `switch case` e simplesmente um `getX` do objeto não interessando o resto, tudo com `else if`, escreveria menos e teria o mesmo resultado. Mas achei diferente a forma do Swift ter essa liberdade.

Me parece que VB também tem uma técnica parecida.

Comment: No segundo caso, em Java ficaria assim: `case "Cat": case "Dog": {lógica} break;`.

Comment: @renan verdade! No segundo caso é possível mesmo, tem razão! Já no primeiro caso é um tanto quanto interessante né! Posso complementar com outros exemplos também. Acrescentei um exemplo de "partial matching"

Comment: De que eu saiba, esse tipo de pattern matching é surgiu primeiro em linguagens de programação funcionais (ML, Haskell, Ocaml, e similares). É especialmente útil quando combinado com tipos de dados algébricos (tagged unions).

Comment: @Mateus Sei que a pergunta já tem muito tempo mas o uso do case let where é totalmente desnecessário se você não usar a variável x nos seus cases. Nesse case você deveria usar ranges nos seu cases e no último se for Swift 4 você pode usar partial range operato se não quiser colocar um limite de idade. Por exemplo `switch age {
case 0...2:
    print("Infant")
case 3...12:
    print("Child")
case 13...19:
    print("Teenager")
case 20...39:
    print("Adult")
case 40...60:
    print("Middle aged")
case 61...:
    print("Elderly")
default:
    print("Invalid")
}`

Comment: Outra coisa nenhuma das respostas sequer abordaram o uso da keyword fallthrough. Um bom exemplo é essa resposta que eu coloquei no site em inglês https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782490/2303865

Comment: Também faltou mostrarem o uso do switch com enumerations em Swift onde não é necessário adicionar o default case (about being exhaustive) Confira a resposta do Nate Cook em relação a isso https://stackoverflow.com/a/26686733/2303865

Comment: Relacionado: Python, a partir da versão 3.10, também suporta pattern matching: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/497534/112052

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Todas as linguagens que permitem [*pattern matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) :P Já sabe o termo disso agora.

Não sei se estou me arriscando em dizer que todas linguagens funcionais suportam este mecanismo. Algumas de um jeito, outras de outro, algumas mais limitadas. Para o bem ou para o mal nenhuma é usada de forma intensa no mercado. Alguns [exemplos na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pattern_matching_programming_languages).

A maioria das linguagens modernas, mesmo não funcionais, estão suportando o mecanismo porque ele é útil. Algumas linguagens estão evoluindo para suportar, [é o caso do C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). Junto com Swift, eram as únicas linguagens de expressivo uso  que suportam isso por algum tempo. Algumas linguagens estão estudando a adoção ou até já dando primeiros passos, para ter um mecanismo semelhante, de uma forma ou de outra, com mais ou menos qualidade. Isto inclui Java, PHP, Python, só para citar as principais que sei.

Claro que outras linguagens de uso menor já possuem o mecanismo, entre elas Rust.

Até onde eu sei C/C++/Objective C, Perl, Ruby, JS, Lua, Delphi, VB.NET, etc. não estão planejando isto tão cedo. Mas pode mudar, fique atento. Algumas possuem mecanismos mais de biblioteca que ajudam, mas não está na linguagem.

Em qualquer linguagem é possível simular isso, mas não será muito conveniente e poderá afetar a performance.

Veja mais em [O que é o Pattern Matching?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445451/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Conceptual.md).

Comment: muito obrigado por responder. Legal saber que C# oferecerá esse recurso. Como eu disse em minha pergunta é claro que a lógica poderia ser expressada sem uso específico do switch. Mas com switch case me pareceu bem menos verboso, inclusive sem uso do break.

Comment: Existe uma ideia rolando de colocar isso em Java. Veja: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305 e http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/

Answer (score 13):

Em Python, desde a versão 3.10 (lançada em outubro de 2020), existe o par de comandos `match` e `case` que podem ser usados como um `switch/case` simples, mas permitem usos bem mais sofisticados com identificação de padrões e execução de expressões:
https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements

---

Abaixo, a resposta original, de 2016:

Em Python houve uma discussão intensa sobre isso nos fóruns onde se discute o futuro da linguagem no começo do ano - mas a inclusão de um comando especializado equivalente ao `switch/case` foi declinada pela comunidade (de novo).

Isso por que se entende que o `if/elif/else` do Python atende a tudo o que é possível fazer com um switch/case e ainda mais expressividade (já que as expressões podem não só ser de matching, mas incluir outros testes também).
O único "custo" é ter que repetir a variável testada em cada ocorrência do `elif` - mas isso também vem acompanhado de maior legibilidade.

Quanto ao `matching` - ele não sendo parte da sintaxe da linguagem, pode ser incorporado em qualquer pacote terceiro e ser usado como uma função normal (assim como acontecem com as expressões regulares em Python).  De novo, vence a legibilidade. Se aparecer algum pacote terceiro de matching que seja realmente um "padrão de facto" ele pode vir a ser incorporado à biblioteca padrão da linguagem. (Intervalos já são suportados em Python há muito tempo)

Comment: muito obrigado por compartilhar sua experiência!

Answer (score 10):

> Aviso: esta resposta é um complemento.

Suportar certos tipo específico de sintaxe - como esta - são quase sempre consideradas de baixa prioridade para diversas linguagens por alguns motivos, dentre eles:

- Pouco benefício para o nível de complexidade de implementar e manter - pensando em compatibilidade com futuras versões e versões anteriores.
- Recursos mais avançados que visivelmente tem impacto no desempenho tendem a ser utilizados de forma errada por muitos usuários, então algumas linguagens preferem se ater ao que é mais simples.
- Existem outras formas melhores de fazer a mesma coisa.

## Exemplos em Java

### Intervalo de idade

Dado um enum:

```java
enum LifeStage {
    Infant(2), Child(12), Teenager(19), Adult(39), MiddleAged(60), Elderly(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    private final int limite;
    LifeStage(int limite) {
        this.limite = limite;
    }
    public boolean match(int age) {
        return age <= limite;
    }
}
```

O código para encontrar a descrição para a idade cai para uma linha usando programação funcional:

```java
int age = 33;
Optional<LifeStage> stage = Arrays.stream(LifeStage.values()).filter(v -> v.match(age)).findFirst();
System.out.println(stage.get());
```

No `switch` original, é desnecessário verificar o intervalo inferior se a idade for sempre `>= 0`.

Entretanto, mesmo que fosse necessário executar uma lógica complexo de qualquer natureza, bastaria alterar o método `match` do enum acima. A grande vantagem é que o método de "busca" não mudaria, pois está desacoplado da implementação.

### Múltiplos valores

Comparar todos os valores sempre é ineficiente. Java postergou o `switch` para strings por esta razão. É muito mais simples e eficiente usar um mapa preparado anteriormente, por exemplo:

```java
Map<String, String> animalCategories = new HashMap<>();
String da = "Domestic Animal";
animalCategories.put("Cat", da);
animalCategories.put("Dog", da);
String ntm = "Never touch me";
animalCategories.put("Lion", ntm);
animalCategories.put("Leopard", ntm);
animalCategories.put("Pantera", ntm);
```

E depois basta consultar:

```java
String dog = "Dog";
String category = animalCategories.get(dog);
System.out.println(category);
```

### Coordenadas

Em Java você precisa de uma classe e se ela for imutável, melhor ainda, basta definir a "descrição" do tipo de coordenada no construtor, podendo usar uma composição de ternários para isto:

```java
class Coord {
    private final int x, y, z;
    private final String desc;

    Coord(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        desc = x == 0 && y == 0 & z ==0 ? "Origin" :
                x != 0 && y == 0 & z ==0 ? "On the x-axis." :
                x == 0 && y != 0 & z ==0 ? "On the y-axis." :
                x == 0 && y == 0 & z !=0 ? "On the z-axis" :
                "Somewhere in space";
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

E para usar:

```java
Coord c = new Coord(3, 0, 0);
System.out.println(c.desc);
```

## Considerações

Não estou afirmando que linguagens como Java são perfeitas. Existem, sim, muitas melhorias que faltam nela e em outras linguagens.

Por outro lado, o que precisa ficar claro na "guerra das linguagens" é que ter o maior conjunto de funcionalidades ou a maior variedade de construções sintáticas não é um fator relevante em seu valor absoluto.

Alguns autores argumentam que uma nova funcionalidade só vale a pena se o o benefício obtido pelo seu uso for maior do que a sobrecarga importa pelo seu uso.

Comment: muito obrigado por compartilhar uma resposta muito legal, completa e bem explicativa e detalhada! Meus parabéns mestre!

Answer (score 8):

Complementando, a título de curiosidade.

Comparando com os exemplos da pergunta, demonstro como ficaria numa linguagem como PHP. Note que praticamente a mesma sintaxe se aplica na linguagem JavaScript, ActionScript e diversas outras com sintaxe similar.

Colocarei apenas uma condição para cada um para reduzir os códigos

## Exemplo 1

SWIFT

```
let age = 33

switch(age){
case let x where x >= 0 && x <= 2:
    print("Infant")
default:
    print("Invalid")
}
```

PHP

```
$age = 33;
switch (true) {
    case ($age >= 0 && $age <= 2):
        echo 'infant';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'invalid';
        break;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var age = 33;
switch (true) {
    case (age >= 0 && age <= 2):
        console.log('infant');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('invalid');
        break;
}
```

## Exemplo 2

SWIFT

```
let string = "Dog"
switch(string){
    case "Cat","Dog":
        print("Domestic animal")
    case "Lion","Leopard","Pantera":
        print("Never touch me")
    default:
        print("By the way, don't touch... :-)")
}
```

PHP

Não muda em nada. Segue a mesma lógica do exemplo:

```
$str = 'Dog';
switch (true) {
    case stripos('Cat, Dog', $str):
        echo 'Domestic animal';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'By the way, don't touch... :-)';
        break;
}
```

JavaScript

Idêntico ao do PHP exceto quanto a função `stripos()`. Basta trocar por função equivalente em JS.

## Exemplo 3

SWIFT

```
let coordinates: (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = (3, 0, 0)
switch (coordinates) {
case (0, 0, 0): // 1
.......
```

Por fim, segue a mesma lógica dos outros dois exemplos acima.

Nesse caso, no PHP, o mais óbvio é usar array e comparar os valores.

```
$arr = array(0, 0 , 0);
switch (true) {
    case (funcao_para_comparar($arr, array(0, 0, 0))):
    ...... faz as coisas que tem que fazer ,etc..


function funcao_para_comparar($arr1, $arr2) {
  ... faz as firulas aqui e pá.
}
```

O importante é que a condição retorne o valor esperado no parâmetro do `switch()`, que nos exemplos acima é booleano `true`.

Como os códigos são repetitivos, acho desnecessário escrever mais do mesmo.

Comment: *"faz as firulas aqui e pá"*. Melhor exemplo ever. :)

Comment: Daniel, obrigado por compartilhar sua experiência comparativa com PHP e JS! Muito legal mesmo! Valeu pela contribuição mestre!

Answer (score 2):

Complementando, nas versões mais recentes do Java (pelo menos [desde o JDK 14](https://openjdk.org/jeps/305)) existem várias formas de *pattern matching* suportadas. **Os testes abaixo foram feitos no JDK 21**.

---

Para algo similar ao primeiro código da pergunta, seria possível fazer:

```java
public void test(Number x) {
    switch (x) {
        case Integer n when 0 <= n && n <= 10 -> {
            System.out.println("p");
        }
        case Integer n when 11 <= n && n <= 20 -> {
            System.out.println("m");
        }
        case Integer n when 21 <= n && n <= 30 -> {
            System.out.println("g");
        }
        default -> {
            System.out.println("x");
        }
    }
}
```

No Java 21 tipos primitivos não são suportados neste tipo de *pattern matching*, por isso o código acima não funciona com `int`, somente com `Integer`. Existe a [JEP 455](https://openjdk.org/jeps/455) que propõe tal funcionalidade, mas no momento em que escrevo esta resposta, ainda não há previsão de quando será implementada.

---

Também é possível fazer algo como o segundo código da pergunta, testando vários valores de uma vez no mesmo `case`:

```java
String s = "dog";
switch (s) {
    case "cat", "dog" -> {
        System.out.println("domestic animal");
    }
    case "lion", "leopard", "pantera" -> {
        System.out.println("never touch me");
    }
    default -> {
        System.out.println("whatever");
    }
}
```

---

Já o terceiro código ainda não é possível. A solução mais próxima é extrair os valores da instância e testá-los separadamente:

```java
// só funciona com records (não pode ser classe)
record Coordinates(int x, int y, int z) {
}

//-------------------------------------------
// e no main:
if (c instanceof Coordinates(int x, int y, int z)) {
    // testar os valores de x, y e z
    if (x == 0 && y == 0 etc...)
}

//-------------------------------------------
// ou testando os valores em cada case
switch (c) {
    case Coordinates(int x, int y, int z) when x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0 -> {
        System.out.println("origin");
    }
    case Coordinates(int x, int y, int z) when y == 0 && z == 0 -> {
        System.out.println("x-axis");
    }
    case Coordinates(int x, int y, int z) when x == 0 && z == 0 -> {
        System.out.println("y-axis");
    }
    case Coordinates(int x, int y, int z) when x == 0 && y == 0 -> {
        System.out.println("z-axis");
    }
    default -> {
        System.out.println("somewhere in space");
    }
}
```

Mas ainda não é possível fazer `case Coordinates(0, 0, _)`, por exemplo. Talvez seja em versões futuras, já que cada versão tem adicionado alguma coisa relacionada ao *pattern matching*. Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados na [JEP 441](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441).