# O que é pattern matching em linguagens funcionais?

Tags: programação-funcional, pattern-matching

Ao ler sobre o paradigma funcional, percebi que a maioria das linguagens possui uma característica em comum, o *pattern matching*.

Contextualizando para um programador como eu, acostumado com os paradigmas orientado a objeto e imperativo, o que seria *pattern matching* e onde ele seria útil? Existe algo parecido em linguagens como C++, C# ou Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em C# existe sim, desde a versão 7 e de lá pra cá estão melhorando bastante o que ele pode fazer. Já vi proposta para por em C++, mas qualquer linguagem pode fazer mais ou menos o mesmo, apenas pode dar muito mais trabalho e precisar de auxílio da biblioteca pra não ficar impraticável, e ficará feio ([respondi sobre Swift](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137912/101), [Rust e outras linguagens possuem alguma forma](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Pattern_matching#Rust)). Alguns exemplos em C#:

```cs
switch (shape) {
    case Square s when s.Side == 0:
    case Circle c when c.Radius == 0:
        return 0;
    case Square s:
        return s.Side * s.Side;
    case Circle c:
        return c.Radius * c.Radius * Math.PI;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentException(message: "shape is not a recognized shape", paramName: nameof(shape));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/PatternMatching.cs).

Esse parece mais óbvio que de acordo com as condições ele entre no `case`, então o primeiro precisa que o dado seja do tipo `Shape` e o objeto que fica armazenado na variável `s` tenha sua propriedade `Side` igual a 0, acontece o mesmo com `Circle` mas aí a condição é outra. De fato, C# consegue fazer o mesmo até com um `if`, mas ainda seria um *pattern matching* porque ele faz mais que analisar uma condição, ele procura por um padrão mais geral, inclusive a maneira como o compilador lida pode ser diferente e otimizado. Aqui está usando uma sintaxe que já pode ser considerada antiga.

```cs
static string Display(object o) => o switch {
    Point { X: 0, Y: 0 }         p => "origin",
    Point { X: var x, Y: var y } p => $"({x}, {y})",
    _                              => "unknown"
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/TypeBounded.fs).

Aqui é mais complexo porque ele está tentando ver se um objeto é de um determinado jeito, no caso o objeto tem que ser do tipo `Point` e as propriedades `X` e `Y` devem valer 0 na primeira opção e se for um ponto, mas não estiver em 0, então deve atribuir as propriedades para variáveis que serão usadas logo em seguida, e termina resultando em um valor que indica que não achou um padrão.

Como o próprio nome diz é um mecanismo que tenta achar padrões em dados, se ele encontrar no dado sendo analisado um padrão igual ao determinado em uma cláusula de *pattern matching* então o código faz alguma coisa vinculada ali, geralmente resultar em um valor, ainda que possa ter algum algoritmo para chegar ali.

Linguagens puramente funcionais não costumam ter um `if`, então este é o mecanismo seletor do que fazer e que toma decisões condicionais. Você pode usá-lo de forma simples e ser como um `if`, ou pode procurar por padrões mais complexos conforme a linguagem deixa. Essas linguagens costumam ter uma forma simples e curta de fazer esta operação. Exemplo:

```
f 0 = 1
f n = n * f (n - 1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Recursive.fs).

Isto está criando uma função `f()` que executará a fórmula de forma recursiva sempre que não atender o primeiro caso que procura pelo padrão que o argumento da chamada da função seja 0, quando for o resultado será 1, caso contrário o padrão então considerará que o argumento é recebido em `n` e este parâmetro é usado para multiplicar com o resultado da chamada da função dela mesma passado o `n` menos 1. Tudo sem `if`, por isso o paradigma é funcional e não imperativo, você não manda fazer algo você cria uma função que faz algo dentro de um padrão.

Em um primeiro momento ele pode parecer algo igual ao `switch`, tanto que tem linguagem que usa a mesma sintaxe, mas ele é muito mais poderoso, não só porque ele pode declarar variáveis locais para uso naquele momento, mas ele pode fazer análises complexas com sintaxe muito simples. Além disso [o `switch` original costuma ser uma otimização de verificação de dados que tem relação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101) e o *pattern matching* por ser mais complexo não costuma poder ser otimizado da mesma forma, mas pode de outras formas.

A não ser em linguagens puramente funcionais que não possuem `if` ou algo semelhante (as não puras possuem) ele é absolutamente desnecessário, no entanto é conveniente quando a lógica que está criando deve executar conforme um padrão de dado encontrado. Não muda muito a não ser que você começa enxergar os problemas de outra forma e você se afasta um pouco do imperativo (diz o que fazer) para ir para o declarativo (diz o que quer). É só um estilo de escrever diferente, é uma forma de expressar algo de forma mais próxima do problema. Por isso ele se populariza entre programadores, e as outras pessoas que programam nunca vão usar :)

Claro, há quem abuse também. Quando é mais simples fazer um `if` ou `switch` simples, então faça assim. É igual recursão que em linguagem imperativa não faz sentido na maioria dos cenários e um laço resolve melhor, mas tem gente que pensa que vão achá-lo mais inteligente se usar a recursão :P

Nem preciso dizer que é o horror dos puristas da orientação a objeto. De fato ele incentiva fazer o código menos orientado a objeto e tomar a decisão sobre que tipo usar no algoritmo e não na estrutura de dados, ele vai contra a corrente do polimorfismo, ainda que o *pattern matching* não deixe de ser uma forma de polimorfismo em certa medida, já que uma função com assinatura diferente será chamada de acordo com o(s) argumento(s) passados, fazendo despacho múltiplo (linguagens mais *mainstream* imperativas não costumam ter essa capacidade mesmo tendo o *pattern matching* mais imperativo). A maioria das linguagens que eram ditas "orientadas a objeto" estão adotando este mecanismo porque querem se afastar da praga da "OOP a qualquer custo" que alguns pregam.

Pode ser mais difícil adicionar novos tipos em uma operação em alguns cenários, mas é mais fácil adicionar operações para os tipos em todos os cenários.

Cada mecanismo no lugar certo.