# Existe diferença entre usar discard ou ignorar o valor retornado por um método?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector

Eu tenho um método parecido com o abaixo:

```
public bool FazerAlgoERetornarSeSucesso() => true;
```

E, em determinado momento, preciso chamar este método, mas não me importo com o resultado. Normalmente eu faria algo como:

```
FazerAlgoERetornarSeSucesso();
```

Porém, em C# é possível usar [*discards*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards). Neste caso, o código ficaria assim:

```
_ = FazerAlgoERetornarSeSucesso();
```

Além da legibilidade ser prejudicada, existe alguma diferença entre usar *discard* e simplesmente ignorar o valor de retorno do método?

Comment: Eu concordo com o @Maniero sobre a melhora da legibilidade. Eu acredito, em minha impressão pessoal, que  o uso da notação de descarte torne a linguagem C# mais familiar para programadores vindos do paradigma funcional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu diria que a legibilidade é melhorada, pelo menos sob certo ponto de vista, pode ser subjetivo.

A segunda forma é mais explícita e isso tem lá sua vantagem de legibilidade, ainda que alguém possa dizer que código que faz nada útil é ruído e aí sim seria menos legível, depende da escola que você usa para definir o que é legível.

Só lembrando que C# nunca proibiu você descartar silenciosamente um resultado de uma chamada de função. Algumas linguagens só deixam você descartar o resultado de forma explícita, caso contrário tem que usar o resultado em uma expressão, incluindo armazenar em uma variável. Agora C# deixa você ser explícito no descarte, mas ainda aceita ser implícito.

E C# não dá erro ou *warning* por não usar uma variável, então também não existe por isso, e o caso específico nem envolve uma variável que seria obrigatória sem o *discard*.

Então um benefício é ser mais explícito e se tornar mais legível.

Já descobri lendo uma [resposta simplesmente do Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401495/221800) que C# não tem obrigação de otimizar isso, mas pode, ele cita Haskell que tem a obrigação de nem calcular. Mas note que isso não é sobre o *discard*, porque poderia fazer até sem a presença dele já que o resultado não é usado mesmo. Porém Haskell é uma linguagem pura, C# não é e essa otimização seria mais complicada, ainda mais se feita pelo [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) já que seria algo que demandaria tempo para identificar se pode otimizar ou não, e isso feito em tempo de execução pode derrotar o possível benefício que traria. Em C# as funções podem ter [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101), e uma otimização de não executar a função porque o resultado pode ser descartado pode deixar de fazer algo interno que afetará outras partes.

Em [outra resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55693941/221800) ninguém contesta que é inútil nesse cenário. Seria o mesmo que não usar o *discard*.

Porém eu vou discordar em um pequeno ponto. Pode ser que hoje seja assim, não sei se mais pra frente, de forma oficial ou não, se a linguagem não faça alguma otimização que ela não faria sem o *discard*. Aí você tem que pensar se vale a pena ou não. Por isso eu seguiria o conselho do Eric Lippert, use se acha que o código ficará mais legível, não se ele ficará mais rápido, a não ser que precise muito da performance e meça na implementação do momento se há vantagem ou não, o que vale hoje pode não valer mais no passado. Já vi muitas coisas mudarem sem ninguém avisar, algumas pra melhor e outras para pior.

## O descarte não foi criado para isso

E lendo também a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#a-standalone-discard) vai ficando mais claro que a utilidade é mesmo onde uma variável seria necessária por alguma razão, não o exemplo relatado na pergunta aqui que a variável não é necessária.

A documentação mostra uma situação que pode fazer diferença se você está retornando uma [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-5.0&?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), então é um caso que você não pode ignorar o resultado sem ser explícito. Mas não é o caso do seu exemplo.

E a documentação também mostra que pode ser um problema porque `_` pode ser uma nome de variável válido e aí essa função tem precedência sobre a construção de linguagem específica, até por questão de compatibilidade. Mas tem que dar os parabéns para quem usou isso como nome de variável.

De fato o mecanismo foi criado para melhorar esse ponto com [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410484/101), tuplas (desconstrução) e até com o bom e velho parâmetro de saída `out`, ele não foi pensado para outras situações, mas não faria sentido proibir uma "desconstrução" de um método que retorna um valor simples, então a sintaxe passou permitir seu uso por questão de paridade com o resto.

Tudo isso desde C# 7. O que o C# 9 trouxe é a paridade para *lambdas* que antes não deixava usar e era esquisito, inclusive em *lambda* faz até mais sentido, tem situação onde ela poderia exigir uma variável.

Criar uma variável e manter um objeto vivo nela sem necessidade tem consequências ruins, mas que podem não ser um problema, ainda que o melhor seria não ter a variável, mas o caso não é uma escolha entre ter uma variável ou não. Nas respostas que eu li mostram casos que faz diferença em outros cenários, o que faz todo sentido.

Se você estivesse comparando:

```
var objeto = FazerAlgoERetornarSeSucesso();
```

e não usasse `objeto` em lugar algum, e

```
_ = FazerAlgoERetornarSeSucesso();
```

O segundo claramente é melhor porque evita um uso acidental de `objeto´ em futura manutenção (conforme discutido em chat :P), além, claro, de criar uma variável que reserva espaço na pilha e segura o objeto retornado por mais tempo, mas

```
FazerAlgoERetornarSeSucesso();
```

dá, hoje, na mesma, internamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Underscore.cs).

## Conclusão

Então vou cravar que nesse cenário, até que alguém prove o contrário que não há vantagem além da subjetiva legibilidade, não há diferença.

Não haverá menos alocação de memória, menos pressão no GC ou mesmo menos reserva de pilha comparando os dois casos porque ambas não existem variáveis. O que mudou em C# 7 é que `_` não é uma variável mais, antes se você usasse esse símbolo era uma variável com esse nome (desde que declarada com um tipo ou `var`) e sem otimização ela precisaria ser reservada. Mas o objeto que é retornado nada muda.