# O que é a expressividade de uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: terminologia, sintaxe, engenharia-de-software, independente-de-linguagem, ciência-da-computação

Vejo descrições dizendo que tal linguagem é mais expressiva do que outras. Então o que quer dizer expressividade de uma linguagem de programação? Como ver essa expressividade em código?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos começar entendendo a palavra. Como expressividade só diz que é sobre algo expressivo vamos ao que importa:

> ex·pres·si·vo |eis| ou |es| (expresso + -ivo) adjectivo
>
> 1. Que exprime.
> 2. Próprio para exprimir.
> 3. Claro, manifesto, significativo.
> 4. Que dá a entender.
> 5. Enérgico.
> 6. Em que há expressão.
>
> "expressivo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/expressivo [consultado em
> 30-08-2022].

Em inglês achei algumas definições interessantes, destaco uma adaptação que fiz:

> a qualidade de uma manifestação mímica, oral, escrita, musical ou plástica que mostra com plena sensação ou significado as ideias ou emoções do autor

Você entende bem uma pessoa expressiva, que não coloca coisas demais, nem de menos, ambas podem confundir. O expressivo depende de colocar tudo o que é necessário para entender bem.

Vamos pôr em imagem?

[image: diversas feições de pessoas]

Dizem por aí que *saudade* só existe um Português e isso é altamente expressivo, mas outras línguas possuem o mesmo com uma palavra, apesar de menos precisão da intenção ou duas ou mais palavras com menos concisão. Não é tão simples falar em expressividade, porque claridade e dar significado pode ser subjetivo em alguns casos, e depende da bagagem que a pessoa carrega, assim como é a legibilidade.

## Programação

Então em programação é algo claro, com **significado** importante, que dá para entender, que expressa bem qual é a intenção do código.

Linguagens mais expressivas são as que ajudam a produzir códigos mais expressivos, mas fica ao cargo do programador fazer o código expressivo ou não.

Não é a mesma coisa, mas é comum que códigos com mais abstrações serem mais expressivos. Por isso códigos mais declarativos tendem ser mais expressivos.

Códigos que dizem mais o que se quer fazer e menos como deve fazer podem ser considerados mais expressivos. Assim um código que chama uma função em vez de mostrar o algoritmo que faz o desejado é mais expressivo.

Há uma tendência de códigos expressivos serem mais curtos e com isso mais legíveis, mas não é uma garantia, principalmente um código mais curto pode ser menos legível. Você pode perder a expressão do que quer fazer ali por deixar mais curto, e se fica menos legível fica mais difícil de entender, fica menos expressivo.

Linguagens mais simples tendem ser mais concretas e, portanto, com menos capacidade de dar expressão ao que se deseja fazer, porque ela tem menos mecanismos que facilitam a expressão, é como se ela tivesse menos nervos na sua face. Um animal tende ser menos expressivo que um ser humano, uma planta menos ainda, mas alguma expressão tem. Toda linguagem, até código de máquina binário tem alguma expressão, bem mínima.

Linguagens verborrágicas podem ser mais expressivas, mas é comum que aconteça o contrário, muita expressão possível, mas que não deixa mais claro. Pode valer para quaisquer linguagens, não precisa ser de programação. O Inglês costuma ser considerada uma linguagem mais expressiva que o Português, ela tende a permitir expressar melhor o que se deseja, em alguns casos por ter uma palavra ou expressão simples que explique melhor o que se deseja.

Aí quando olhamos para a computação temos uma definição mais divulgada e escrutinada, achei [este artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressive_power_(computer_science)).

Então a expressividade é uma **medida de potência da expressão**. Destaco o trecho:

> Quanto mais expressiva for uma linguagem, maior será a variedade e a quantidade de ideias que ela pode ser usada para representar.

Então a linguagem mais expressiva é aquela que pode ser profunda de forma simples, geralmente de forma curta.

Lá no verbete descobrimos que a discussão sobre a expressividade de linguagens de programação não é algo tão bem estudado e formalizado, então, assim como muitos assuntos de computação, as pessoas falam de forma mais intuitiva do que fundamentada. Isso vai formando fundamento, ainda que com menor peso. O que a maioria acha pode ir se consolidando como a verdade. Mas basta alguém trazer algo com mais peso e vai tudo por água abaixo.

E lá diz algo que confirma o que eu disse, mostrando que expressividade demais, ou seja, uma linguagem muito formal, pode inviabilizar porque fica mais complicado fazer o código ser escrito. Tome Haskell como exemplo. É dito que qualquer código que compile nela está certo (sob certo ponto de vista), o problema é fazer um código compilar nela. É tanta expressividade, é tanto mecanismo que deve tomar conta, que complica muito fazer.

Outro exemplo é Rust que precisa expressar tempo de vida de objetos para compilar e funcionar corretamente. Algumas linguagens como C/C++ preferiram não ter essa expressão e deixar dar erro. Outras preferiram não ter isso e ficar menos eficiente. Mas essas linguagens são mais expressivas no sentido de que implicitamente lida com algumas questões para o programador, algo que C/C++, e até Rust em certa medida, precisam ser mais explícitas, porém com maior poder de expressão maneiras diferentes de trabalhar aquilo.

Percebe que a expressividade depende, como em muita coisa em computação? C# é mais claro de entender gerenciamento de memória, mas tem menos poder de cuidar de todos os aspectos, cada uma com sua capacidade de expressão.

Quando vai lidar com ponteiros diretamente tem mais precisão no que quer, mas tem que cuidar de mais coisas, você deve escrever mais coisas, mesmo que mínima e eventualmente fique até mais curto.

O problema é quando você tem que escrever algo para expressar sem necessidade. Por exemplo uma linguagem que não tem um `for each` será menos expressiva porque precisa fazer a repetição em uma sequência de dados de forma mais bruta, concreta, sem necessidade. Mas uma linguagem que não tem um `for` bruto pode não ter capacidade de expressar a repetição de forma mais criativa, menos usual, então depende do que está analisando.

Uma definição que parece bem boa:

> Capacidade de uma linguagem de programação para expressar a solução de um problema:
>
> a) com o caminho mais próximo da formulação original do problema,
>
> b) de forma clara, natural, intuitiva e concisa,
>
> c) em termos de outros (sub)problemas resolvidos.

[Um paper muito citado](https://jgbm.github.io/eecs762f19/papers/felleisen.pdf).

## Exemplos

```
3.times { 
   println 'Hello' 
}
```

É bem expressivo não?

Alguns dirão que seria mais se a linguagem permitisse:

```
3.times 
   println 'Hello'
```

Assim você tirou o que poderia ser considerado irrelevante. Tem quem diria que o ponto não é necessário. Mas não é tão simples, redundância pode ser importante em certos cenários, principalmente para o compilador, mas até para o humano.

Afinal, qual código é mais expressivo, um que faz uma expressão matemática de forma direta, ou uma que guarda em uma variável sem necessidade só para nomear a ação? Nem sempre legibilidade é o mesmo que expressividade.

Tem linguagem que permitirá

```cs
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 3)) { 
    WriteLine("Hello"); 
}
```

Ou

```cs
0..3.ForEach(x => WriteLine("Hello"));
```

Dá para questionar qual é mais expressivo. E o expressivo pode ser mais ilegível para alguém que não conhece o mecanismo.

Nem todos códigos aqui funcionam em alguma linguagem válida, é só para demonstrar.

E finalmente algumas serão assim:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
   System.out.println("Hello"); 
}
```

Que interessante, o `for` em si foi até mais curto, mas ele não é bem expressado, expõe o mecanismo, o "como fazer" em vez de "o que fazer". Expressividade não é o mesmo que concisão, mas muitas vezes elas andam juntas, deu para perceber nos exemplos?

Já a forma de imprimir no console é mais longo e me parece menos expressivo, você tem que lidar com o que deveria ser irrelevante.

Só para mostrar algo menos expressivo ainda:

```
i = 0 
:inicio 
print "Hello" 
i = i + 1 
if i < 3 goto inicio
```

Colocar tipo explicitamente é mais ou menos expressivo? Me parece que é mais, é um contrato extra, é uma opção para demonstrar mais claramente que dado quer usar.

Usar o operador de incremento (`++`) não é mais expressivo que fazer duas operações para alcançar o mesmo resultado?

COBOL parece língua corrente, é mais expressivo? Me parece que em geral não é.

Pega o `async` e `await` que algumas linguagens possuem. É muito expressivo fazer assincronismo com isso nas linguagens que disponibilizaram o mecanismo, em alguns casos pela biblioteca padrão. Antes você tinha que escrever uma máquina de estados, uma forma de controlar a troca de contexto, chamar funções especiais, tinha que escrever muito código com chance de cometer erros, antes era menos expressivo. Em muitos casos ser mais expressivo significa que tem mais *syntax sugar*.

Quando você aplica certos tais padrões de projeto (*design patterns*) na linguagem, por exemplo quando tem o padrão Observer em um mecanismo de `event`, isso é ser mais expressivo.

LINQ do C# é muito mais expressivo do que varrer coleções de dados de forma manual. Não é necessariamente melhor, expressividade não é panaceia.

Até poder dizer `#cyan` ou `0x00FFFF` ou `rgb(0, 255, 255)` para determinar uma cor, isso mostra diferenças de expressão. Então até a forma de escrever um literal há poder de expressão.

Pega o tal do *[pattern matching](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410484/101)* do C# que elimina a necessidade de fazer um *cast* em objetos para adaptar ao tipo necessário, é algo que dá muita expressividade.

`/^_[0-9]{8}$/` isso é conciso, mas é expressivo? Você entende melhor que um código mais longo como [nesta biblioteca](http://blog.flimflan.com/ReadableRegularExpressions.html)?

Eu sei qual é mais legível, mas a expressividade é a mesma, é pior ou melhor?

## Linguagens expressivas

[Programming languages ranked by expressiveness](https://redmonk.com/dberkholz/2013/03/25/programming-languages-ranked-by-expressiveness/).

Rankings foram feitos para causar polêmica :D, mas é um critério declarado. Eu discordo fortemente.

Note que DSLs tendem ser mais expressivas porque elas "entendem" o domínio. Linguagens funcionais se dão muito bem por serem mais declarativas, assim como as DSLs. Pena não ter aí uma linguagem lógica, pelo menos uma que eu sei que é, porque tendem ser bastante expressivas.

Linguagens com diferentes níveis de expressividade são difíceis de serem traduzidas entre si. É claro que depende de cada mecanismo, mas em cada um deles sem o mesmo nível fica complicado portar o código de uma linguagem para outra, pelo menos de forma idiomática.

## Conclusão

Acho que podemos dizer que ser mais expressivo é poder dar mais semântica de forma simples (a ser definido). Ser expressivo é bom para usar, mas é ruim para aprender.

Eu não vou entrar muito na teoria da coisa porque isso pouco importa para o programador comum, e tem *link* para se aprofundar se quiser.

Pesquisando vi que algumas pessoas tem visões diferentes sobre o tema. Não tenha isto aqui como definitivo e canônico.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tenho medo de quando a linguagem "é expressiva demais" e acaba criando um código de difícil manutenção, por ter sido adaptada a ser "fácil", o que acaba sendo limitado no final.