# Diferença entre representação, expressão e sintaxe de uma linguagem de programação

Tags: xml, terminologia, sintaxe, teoria-da-computação

Recentemente, me foi informado que Lógica de Primeira Ordem (FOL) ou Lógica de Descrição e XML não são comparáveis porque lidam com escopos conceituais diferentes. Nesse caso, o XML foi apresentado como uma *expressão* enquanto um arquivo TBX, ou FOL, por exemplo, é uma *representação*. O  TBX, por exemplo, é uma representação *expressa* como um arquivo XML (???).
Também se encaixa nesse tema o termo sintaxe, que é a forma como compomos a sequência de textos e comandos na linguagem de programação.

Nesse tema também se enquadra o termo *sintaxe* que é a forma como compomos a sequência de textos e comandos na linguagem de programação.
Enfim, **estou procurando mais informações que esclareçam essa diferença entre representação, expressão e sintaxe de uma linguagem de programação.**

Acho que se trata de diferenciar a linguagem lógica (regrada), da notação como JSON e XML que são representações de informação independentes de linguagem de programação.

Comment: Topics: [O que é a expressividade de uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/563253/o-que-%c3%a9-a-expressividade-de-uma-linguagem-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o?rq=1)

Comment: O texto que colocou é interessante, mas minha questão vai em outro sentido. Eu fiz umas alterações no texto para tentar reapresentar o problema. Estou estudando isso há dois dias e ainda não entendi muito bem a diferença, mas acho que se trata de diferenciar linguagem lógica, regrada, de notação como JSON e XML que são representações de informação independentes de linguagem de programação.

Comment: @Douglas, poderia adicionar o texto no comentário em forma de texto no corpo da pergunta? Basta clicar no botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/574579/edit).