# O que é o Pattern Matching?

Tags: característica-linguagem, elixir, pattern-matching

Estou lendo a respeito do [*pattern matching*](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html) e ainda continuo bem confuso a respeito desta característica por ser algo novo para mim.

Veja uns exemplos:

```
{:ok, result} = {:ok, 12}
```

> {:ok, 12}

e

```
12 = result
```

> 12

## Perguntas

1. O que é o *pattern matching*?
2. Esta característica só esta presentes em linguagens funcionais ou
   existe em outras linguagens com outros paradigmas como Python ou C#?
3. Qual é a finalidade do *pattern matching*?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que é pattern matching em linguagens funcionais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410484/o-que-%c3%a9-pattern-matching-em-linguagens-funcionais)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O que é o pattern matching?

Isso não é específico de Elixir, e até mesmo de linguagens funcionais, embora faça mais sentido nelas. Toda linguagem séria *mainstream*, especialmente as que gostam de código curto, significativo e que goste de matemática, um dia terá esse mecanismo (as outras são para não programadores, ainda que alguns programadores ainda usem).

É uma forma de tomar uma decisão baseado em um padrão encontrado em um objeto (no sentido amplo do que é objeto).

Por padrão entenda que é encontrar alguma forma específica, incluindo seu tipo ([estrutural ou nominal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101)) e os valores constantes no objeto específico. Então você pode dizer que quer fazer um cálculo ou pegar um valor **se** o objeto sendo analisado for do tipo tal e no campo ou argumento `x` tem o valor específico.

Sabe quando você tem um algoritmo que identifica se uma foto é de alguém ou de um bicho ou tenta descobrir que objeto é? Ou uma música, ou um texto plagiado? Tudo isso é um algoritmo que tenta achar semelhanças com algo que ele já conhece e dizer se é igual ou não. Claro que a ideia nesses casos nem é pegar se é exato, mas sim se tem semelhança suficiente para considerar que é aquilo que está procurando.

Outro bom exemplo e mais exato é o RegEx. Ele é só um *pattern matching* de texto, ele tenta achar um formato específico no texto.

O *pattern matching* na programação é a mesma coisa, é exato e busca padrões muito mais simples envolvendo uma matemática básica. É um recurso que tenta encontrar uma situação no objeto que importa para o que está fazendo.

Lembrando que um RegEx pode só dizer se achou o padrão ou modificar o conteúdo baseado nesse padrão, então não é apenas tomar decisões não relacionadas, a decisão pode ser modificar o objeto de um jeito específico. O mesmo vale para o mecanismo da linguagem de programação.

Note que ele não costuma ser uma forma imperativa de tomar decisões. Um exemplo que se costuma usar seria assim:

```
fatorial 0 = 1
fatorial n = n * fatorial (n - 1)
```

Aí você está definindo uma função, ou duas olhando de outra forma. O compilador (ou *runtime*) tomará uma decisão de qual delas deve chamar baseado no seu valor.

Se você não está acostumado com sintaxe funcional, em outras linguagens mais imperativas seria algo assim:

```
function fatorial(0) {
    return 1;
}
function fatorial(n) {
    return n * fatorial(n - 1);
}
```

Quando chama `fatorial(5)` ele entra na segunda função e lá chama novamente a segunda função como `fatorial(4)` conforme a expressão da chamada ali, que por sua vez chamará de novo, agora com 3, e vai chamando sucessivamente até que em determinado momento a chamada será `fatorial(0)`, nesse momento ele não chama mais a segunda função, ele chama a primeira porque tem um padrão melhor, mais específico, quando o argumento da função é 0 então a primeira tem um *matching* (casamento) melhor, e é ela que é executada, e assim ela encerra as repetições.

Note que são duas funções completamente distintas apesar de estarem escritas juntas (até para ser mais legível), é como se fosse um *overload*, mas a diferença da assinatura é o valor do argumento.

Em linguagem imperativa você faria com uma função e teria um `if` para decidir quando encerrar. Em linguagens funcionais não precisa disso no código.

Para quem não está acostumado a sintaxe de certas linguagens funcionais parece confusa, e de fato é um pouco, mas tem uma lógica, não é algo tirado da cartola. É uma questão de costume e prática. Mas de fato apesar de dar uma flexibilidade interessante pode atrapalhar o entendimento.

No seu exemplo ele está avaliando apenas se a expressão é válida, sem especificar nenhuma ação a não ser que o resultado é o valor que encontrou.

## Seu exemplo

O que está ali no código não é uma simples atribuição de valores, mas na prática você pode considerar que é. Então `:ok` bate com `:ok` e `result` encaixa com `12`, portanto ele assume esse valor.

Essa forma de código não faz tanto sentido assim porque é um literal, você está vendo o que é. Não é que não possa ser usado, pode, e muita gente usa quando os dados são relacionados, mas esse caso específico costuma ocorrer como um retorno de uma função, ou seja, uma função que faz alguma coisa, em vez de simplesmente retornar um resultado ele retorna uma estrutura que tem o resultado e e um `atom` indicando se deu certo porque a função pode não ter conseguido processar o que queria e o resultado não é criado. Então esse `{:ok, 12}` geralmente é um retorno de função e não o literal escrito diretamente, algo assim:

```
{:ok, result} = divide(4, 2)
```

Então provavelmente você teria um `:ok` batendo e um `2` para ser casado com o `result`.

Mas isto:

```
{:ok, result} = divide(4, 0)
```

Você teria retornando um `:error` que não bate com `:ok` esperado, portando está fora do padrão e o resto nem interessa mais. Aí se tentar usar um `result` para alguma coisa dará erro. A decisão se vai atribuir um valor foi baseada no padrão encontrado.

Para quem não sabe `:ok` não é uma variável, é um literal do tipo `atom`.

Só não ache que tem mágica aí, o compilador coloca as decisões para você. O paradigma funcional entende que os códigos devem ser enxutos e se puder expressar mais matematicamente e menos verbosamente então deve ser feito assim. Essas linguagens são mais declarativas, portanto [você diz o que quer e não diz o que fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101), a linguagem se vira com o que fazer.

Mas se quer fazer algo útil completo precisa escrever algo mais:

```
write_line(case divide(4, 0) do
    {:ok, result} -> deu certo, o valor é #{result}"
    {:error, _} -> "lamento, deu erro"
end)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/MultiDispatch.exs).

Na página seguinte à *linkada* na pergunta mostra como ele funciona tomando decisões de forma mais tradicional.

Pode ter algum erro no código e pode ter um jeito mais fácil de fazer, não costumo usar Elixir, mas a ideia é essa.

> Esta característica só esta presentes em linguagens funcionais ou existe em outras linguagens com outros paradigmas como Python ou C#?

Existe em qualquer linguagem que acharam ele útil, [incluindo em C# e outras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410484/101). Claro que em geral elas costumam ter mais limitações, por exemplo não pode decidir uma chamada de função só pela sua assinatura considerando o valor, até pode tomar essa decisão, mas precisa ser mais explícito, o compilador não toma a decisão sozinho como ocorre em linguagens mais funcionais.

Em C# por exemplo você pode ter algo assim:

```csharp
(var ok, var result) = TryDivide(4, 0);
```

Mas não faz *pattern matching*, as duas variáveis serão atribuídas e depois se quiser terá que ser explícito no uso com um `if`. E se o valor é inválido, nada impede de você usar o `result`. Ao contrário de Elixir, você pode fazer algo errado com isso. Mas hoje dá para fazer algo assim que é mais seguro:

```csharp
WriteLine(TryDivide(4, 0) switch {
    (true, result) => $"deu certo, o valor é {result}",
    (false, _) => "lamento, deu erro" //não usará a variável mesmo, então descarta
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Functional.cs).

Por isso apesar de ter *pattern matching* a linguagem ainda é imperativa, você diz o que fazer, o que em e muitos casos é necessário mesmo.

Parte da diferença é pela linguagem não ter o `atom`, mas poderia usar um `enum` no lugar, porque no fundo é (quase) a mesma coisa. De certa forma um booleano é um `enum` mais específico. Um `enum` deixaria mais explícito que tem um `ok` ou `error` e não apenas se o `ok` é verdadeiro ou falso.

> Qual é a finalidade do pattern matching?

[Respondi em parte sobre Elixir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252572/101).

Podemos dizer que é uma forma de simplificar códigos onde deve decidir o que fazer dentro de condições complexas (ou nem tanto). Em vez de simplesmente fazer uma comparação (que até pode ser complexa e envolver várias nuances) você diz algo que espera encontrar em um objeto e se esse padrão for encontrado deve executar uma ação específica, provavelmente resultando em um valor através de uma expressão. Então de uma certa forma ele substitui um `if` (de fato em linguagens funcionais um pouco mais puras é a única forma de tomar decisões).

Ele é um `switch` que todos conhecem bem mais sofisticado que normalmente é apenas um *pattern matching* simplificado, já que o único padrão que ele adota é se o valor de um objeto tem um valor específico.

Com o *pattern matching* você pode verificar se o objeto é de um determinado tipo, pode analisar se ele tem determinada estrutura, se tem certos valores em parte de sua sua estrutura e considerando os demais como parte variável, enfim se atende determinados critérios de como o objeto se comporta de forma bastante flexível (a linguagem precisa ser preparada para cada flexibilidade possível). E é possível ter condições mais sofisticadas além do padrão, exatamente como ocorre com um `if` (em geral isso é uma verificação extra ao padrão).

Quem está muito acostumado com linguagens imperativas sofre para se adaptar com essa sintaxe, especialmente em linguagens que permitem uma forma mais imperativa opcionalmente, a pessoa tende a usar o que ela acostumou.