# O que são tipos de dados algébricos (algebraic data types ou ADTs)?

Tags: terminologia, tipagem, programação-funcional, teoria-dos-tipos, tipos-algébricos

Eventualmente leio em alguns artigos relacionados a programação funcional o termo *algebraic data types*, mas não sei muito bem o que são eles e acabo ficando meio perdido.

- O que são tipos de dados algébricos (*algebraic data types*)?
- O que o difere de um tipo de dados "não algébrico", por exemplo, um *array* do JavaScript?
- Tem alguma coisa a ver com a matemática (vide nome "algébrico")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tudo em computação tem algo a ver com matemática, computação é matemática, não é uma invenção diferente. Computações são abstrações que usamos para expressar e resolver problemas, igual à matemática.

Tecnicamente você já usa o Algebraic Data Type porque ele é um tipo fruto da composição de outros tipos. Então um objeto certamente é um ADT.

As técnicas básicas de composição são a soma e o produto.

Esses tipos que você já costuma criar (como classes, protótipos, tuplas, registros e até vetores) são tipos baseados em produto. Cada tipo da composição tem seu espaço e coexistem normalmente. Isso é um ADT.

Já a enumeração é um tipo de soma, ou seja, você trabalha com **um** valor entre muitos possíveis (muitos podem ser apenas 2). Em um *enum* você tem vários membros indicando situações diferentes, mas o valor que usará é apenas um deles. Uma *union* que algumas linguagens possuem (algumas variações como *tagged union* ou *variant* também) é uma estrutura composta por membros diferentes, geralmente de tipos diferentes (ao contrário da *enum*), mas que só um valor prevalecerá e estará disponível. Isso é um ADT.

A maior diferença é que nesse tipo de estrutura espera-se algo fechado, ou seja, não haverá alterações na sua composição ou comportamento (inclusive por herança). Pode ver mais em [Uma enumeração deve ser constante no tempo de vida da solução?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101). Por isso os tipos de produto tendem a serem mudados ao longo do tempo ou até dentro da própria execução da aplicação. Os tipos baseados em soma isso é mais difícil acontecer, ou nem deveria acontecer.

Então costumamos chamar de ADT apenas os tipos que foram criados para serem constantes, que indique algo estável, ainda que estritamente falando os outros também sejam ADT.

Vejo uma tendência das pessoas chamarem de ADT esses tipos de soma que são compostos por valores específicos. Ele é um ADT, mas é uma forma mais específica. Vou dar um exemplo em Rust porque sei que o AP anda estudando o assunto:

```rust
enum Optional<T> {
    None,
    Some(T)
}
```

Então esse tipo chamado `Optional` tem um valor de dois possíveis. Ou ele é o valor chamado de `None`, portanto é um valor que não existe e não pode fazer qualquer coisa extra com ele; **ou** ele tem um valor chamado `Some`, que tem um componente extra junto dele, e no exemplo o valor extra pode ser um valor genético estabelecido por `T` em cada situação, e aí pode fazer algo com esse valor.

Usaria algo assim usando [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445451/101):

```rust
resultado : Optional<i32> = TentaObterResultado();
match resultado {
    Some(valor) => println!("O valor é {}", valor),
    None => println!("Não deu certo")
}
```

Poderia ser mais sofisticado que isso:

```rust
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Optional.rs).

Parece uma classe, né? Mas só um deles pode ocorrer em cada situação. Isso é uma *tagged union*, que algumas pessoas chamam de ADT. Sim, é um ADT, mas todas composições de tipo o são se a expectativa é ser fechado.

Outra diferença que podemos observar, embora seja dependente de implementação é que você não tem que se preocupar com certos detalhes do tipo, a linguagem já definiu alguns comportamentos padrões para um ADT. Por isso algumas pessoas dizem que eles são apenas `enums` glorificados. Ele é muito simples, não tem que cuidar dos detalhes que normalmente precisa em uma classe ou `struct`.

Eu diria que o termo acaba sendo usado para dizer que tem um tipo de soma poderoso, mas de forma simplificada, com tudo pronto, mais ou menos como ocorre com os *records* que andam em moda agora e várias linguagens estão implementando, e que só são classes (um tipo de produto) com algumas coisas prontas para você. O que as pessoas chamam de ADT são só tipos de soma pronto para uso, mas formalmente é um tipo composto fechado.