# O que significa "ad-hoc" no contexto da computação?

Tags: terminologia

Eventualmente vejo alguns termos precedidos por "*ad-hoc*", mas ainda não consegui entender direito o que significa.

Quando utiliza-se "*ad-hoc*" em um termo relacionado à computação, existe um significado comum? O que significa "*ad-hoc*"?

Por exemplo, *ad-hoc polymorphism* seria um nome no qual *"ad-hoc"* não tem significado especial? Ou há um significado comum em *"ad-hoc"* que também pode ser utilizado em outras situações?

Comment: Creio que um bom começo é entender a locução. https://dicionario.priberam.org/ad%20hoc - ad-hoc é "fim específico", "finalidade específica".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O termo significa que algo existe para um fim específico, que tem uma característica só para o objeto de que se trata ali.

Eu acredito, mas não tenho certeza que [*ad hoc polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism) indique que é a forma mais específica de polimorfismo, que se contrapõe à forma mais genérica, que de fato chama-se [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101). Eu explico sobre polimorfismo, incluindo o *ad hoc* em [Polimorfismo em linguagem procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101) ([também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214767/101) e [ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/310083/101), siga os *links*), mas acho que a pergunta não é sobre isto.

Os termos sempre podem ser usados em contextos próprios e podem inclusive surgir novos.

Encontrei 3 definições específicas [na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc), podem existir mais:

> Em engenharia de software, a expressão ad hoc é utilizada para
> designar ciclos completos de construção de softwares que não foram
> devidamente projectados em razão da necessidade de atender a uma
> demanda específica do usuário, ligada a prazo, qualidade ou custo. A
> expressão também é citada no nível 1 do CMMI, quando a coleta de dados
> para indicadores é feita ad hoc, ou seja, para resolver determinado
> problema ou realizar uma tarefa específica.
>
> Modelos informais utilizados pelo desenvolvedor de software costumam
> ser ad hoc, como rabiscar uma ideia para obter maior clareza e
> simplificação da realidade. Porém, esses modelos não oferecem uma
> linguagem básica que possa ser compartilhada com outras pessoas
> facilmente.
>
> Na tecnologia das redes de computadores, uma comunicação é ad hoc
> quando dois ou mais dispositivos se comunicam diretamente pela rede
> sem fio, não necessitando de um nó intermediário (servidor, ponto de
> accesso, estação, etc).

Uma delas é corroborada pela [versão em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) que é um pouco mais confiável.

A ideia de fazer algo que funcione, que resolve, ou quebra-galho, uma gambi, ou um código *throw away* é [defendida no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1786735/221800). Mas lá há quem chame de código escrito *on the fly* de *ad hoc*.

[Há quem disse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1786789/221800) inclusive que o termo é usado para se opor ao software de prateleira (COTS), o que aqui chamados de específico mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Aproveitando o link que o @Bacco comentou: https://dicionario.priberam.org/ad%20hoc

> (locução latina que significa "para isso") Que se destina a um fim
> específico.

Ouvi esse termo muitas vezes relacionado a *queires* de banco de dados, o que da pra entender bem a sua aplicação também na informática:

Um sistema qualquer permite consultar um produto por nome, logo temos uma query "genérica" que é aplicada para toda as consultas de produto por nome, que inclusive por ser assim, pode até ser encapsulada numa *stored procedure*:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUTO WHERE NOME='BATATAS'
```

Onde apenas informamos o valor de "BATATAS". Agora se tem uma situação que precisa consultar um produto por nome, mas também um produto que esteja ativo, que tenha sido cadastrado numa data específica, etc, isso seria uma consulta *Ad hoc*, ou seja, vai ser usada para um fim específico, diferente da query "genérica" que tem um propósito "geral".

Sobre *Ad hoc polymorphism*, o conceito seria o mesmo, um "polimorfismo específico" ou "para um determinado fim". E como seria isso?

Bem, o polimorfismo (ou muitas formas) é um dos conceitos da orientação a objeto onde um método pode se comportar de forma diferentes, tendo o mesmo contrato, em classes diferentes.

Podemos aplicar o polimorfismo com interfaces ou apenas classes:

```
public class Calculo
{
    public int Calcular(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}


public class CalculoAlternativo : Calculo
{
    public int Calcular(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
}
```

Aqui vemos o polimorfismo do método `Calcular`, ele tem a mesma assintura (nome e parâmetros), mas se comporta de forma diferente na classe `Calculo` e `CalculoAlternativo`.

O polimorfismo *ad hoc* é aquele que é criado para um fim específico, ou seja, os parâmetros são diferentes e ele deve ter um comportamento diferente para atender um fim específico. Isso pode ser implementado através da sobrecarga, ou *overloading*:

```
public class Calculo
{
    public int Calcular(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public int Calcular(int num1, int num2, bool soPositivo)
    {
        var resultado = num1 - num2;
        
        if (soPositivo && resultado < 0)
        {
            resultado = 0;
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Neste caso, o método tem o mesmo nome, mas se comporta de forma diferente, e recebe parâmetros diferentes.

Referências:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ad-hoc-inclusion-parametric-coercion-polymorphisms/

http://www.btechsmartclass.com/java/java-polymorphism.html

https://catonmat.net/cpp-polymorphism