# A estrutura condicional "if else" é mais performática que um "switch case"?

Tags: java, desempenho

Há grandes diferenças de performance entre a estrutura condicional `if else` e a `switch case` dentro de um programa?

Comment: Sempre bom lembrar que `if` merece um certo cuidado para ser comparado com `switch`. Apesar de erroneamente ensinado como alternativa um do outro, em boa parte das linguagens (em especial do C, que é referência de muitas outras) a natureza de ambos é completamente diferente. `if` é estrutura condicional, assim como else e o operador ternário. O `switch` não é uma estrutura condicional de fato. Sua natureza é de jumplist, equivale a um `goto`. E é por isso que precisa do `break`, CASO você não queira o cascade (o `break` faz outro "goto"), que por sinal é poderoso quando usado voluntariamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma geral não. Não dá para garantir nada porque existem maneiras diferentes de uso, algumas equivocadas mas ainda possíveis, além do que a forma da implementação não é algo especificada pela linguagem, assim não dá para garantir qual é mais rápido mesmo usando situação idêntica apenas falando da linguagem, teria que observar a implementação específica que pode depender da versão.

Considerando tudo isso, o normal é o `switch` ser mais eficiente porque ele foi criado principalmente para ser isso, pelo menos originalmente era essa ideia, e C o adotou antes de mais nada para ser mais rápido, e expressar melhor certas situações veio de brinde, não era o principal que se queria atingir.

Java "comprou" essa ideia e na implementação mais comum faz, até onde eu sei, o mesmo que C, que é usar um mecanismo de *jump table* quando adota o `switch` e assim tende a tornar a execução um pouco mais rápida. Para saber mais: [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/101).

Mas entenda que o `switch` provavelmente será usado como [sintaxe para um mecanismo completamente diferente](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) que é o [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445451/101). Aí a conversa é bem diferente e se aproxima mais a um `if` metido a besta do que uma otimização. Então essa pergunta fica mais complicada.

Todos são mecanismos de seleção do que fazer, mas a maneira de funcionar é completamente diferente.